# how to display db field value in a list in jsp page?

Tags: jsp

I have a `jsp` page which contains text box called `student_name` and `search` button in a form. When the user will enter some name in a text box then press on search button. Then it will check the entered name from db ex. `Student` table . if found then I need to display  the student `name` and student `number` in same `jsp`. Each time I will search for single record only.

My question is. How to add the each record in jsp table ? 
 Any suggestions please??

Student  list: used table here.

```
SL.no.     student_name
 1.              ABC
 2.              Def
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post any relevant code you have tried, and we can try to help you based on that

Comment: check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> How to add the each record in jsp table

First create a `Student` class to hold student information like:

```
public class Student {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;

   public Student(){}

   //getters and setters
}
```

then create a servlet to handle `GET` & `POST` requests like:

```
@WebServlet("/studentServlet")
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

                //get here user entered name of student to search

                //search in student table of database

                // and add found students to studentList
                List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

               //add studentList to request
               request.setAttribute("studentList", studentList);

            //forward to search jsp page
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("searchPage.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

in jsp show students using [JSTL](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) like:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="currentStudent">
    <tr>
       <td>  ${currentStudent.id}   </td>
       <td>  ${currentStudent.name}   </td>       
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  I got an idea.